# Using Akima package linear interpolation: interp for a very irregular grid

Tags: r, matrix, grid, interpolation

I have the below grid with a function evaluated only at the points:

I am having trouble setting up the data x,y, and z so I can use

```
interp(x,y,z)
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible?  Akima says it supports irregular spaced grid.

Data:

```
categoryvector=21
ninterp=4
points = seq(0,categoryvector,by=ceil(((categoryvector - 0)/(ninterp - 1))))
if(!categoryvector%in%points){points=c(points,categoryvector)}
if(!1%in%points){points=c(points,1); points=sort(points)}
keepers = data.table(expand.grid(prod1vint1=points,prod1vint2=points))
points1 = c(keepers$prod1vint1,0:categoryvector,rep(0,categoryvector+1),rep(categoryvector,categoryvector+1),0:categoryvector)
points2 = c(keepers$prod1vint2,rep(0,categoryvector+1),0:categoryvector,0:categoryvector,rep(categoryvector,categoryvector+1))

z =data.table(points1=points1,points2=points2,z=rnorm(length(points2),10,3))
```

Making the grid: [image]

Comment: Please share a reproducible example.

Comment: @Axeman  ok added a reproducible example, trying to interpolate or use interp on z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `interpp` not `interp`.

Comment: So this means I don't have to setup the matrix, and can have any actual convex set of points to do interpolation over?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you just throw a set of coordinates and values at it and it'll return nice gridded values in return.(You must specify the grid, of course.)

Comment: It says it's deprecated and to use interpp...that seems like an odd warninig, since that was what i was using!

Comment: Very odd! Ignore and forge ahead, is what I say.